# SQL profiler shows wrong locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, locks, sql-server-profiler

i have a specific select that produces locks. I am tracing them with profiler. 
Here is what profiler says:

```
Lock:Acquired <no textdata> OBJECTID:57576312   
Lock:Acquired 1:515848                        
Lock:Acquired (59855d342c69)      
Lock:Released (59855d342c69) 
Lock:Released 1:515848
```

So what does sp_locks (and sys.dm_tran_locks) tell me:

```
7   357576312   0   TAB                                     IX  GRANT
7   357576312   1   PAG 1:515848                            IU  GRANT
7   357576312   1   KEY (59855d342c69)                      U   GRANT
```

So who is right? One is telling me that locks are released, the other tells me that they are held.

I am a little bit confused ;-P

**// Edit
Please use following code to reproduce this behaviour:**

```
-- create tables

ALTER DATABASE <insert database name here> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].Bla (
id int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].BlaDetails (
Id int Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BlaId int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY  (BlaId) REFERENCES Bla(id)
)

-- insert data
insert into bla(id) values(1)
insert into bladetails(blaid) values(1)
```

Now open profiler, trace Lock:Acquired, Lock:Released. And open a new connection with following code:

```
begin tran
set transaction isolation level read committed
select * from bla with(UPDLOCK) inner join bladetails d on bla.id = d.blaId where bla.id = 1

sp_lock @@spid
```

Best regards, Josef

Comment: Both can be correct, if `sp_lock` is showing you locks taken earlier. For starters, `SELECT` isn't going to take out update locks (unless explicitly told to do so with a hint).

Comment: @Jeroen Well, that is the question. According to the articles I've found in the www, sp_locks should show the current granted locks and not those that have been released earlier. And you're right, SELECT does not take update locks. I used a tablehint WITH(UPDLOCK) for some reasons. Sry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Yes, `sp_lock` shows only the currently held locks -- what I meant with my statement was to ask if there could possibly be statements, other than the `SELECT`, executed earlier, that were still holding those locks that profiler shows as having been released -- that'd be the easiest explanation for the discrepancy. (A transaction that's inadvertently still open would be another possibility -- nested transactions don't exist in SQL Server, so you'd still only "see" one.)

Comment: @Jeroen No, there is only one Query. I will show you what I've done: `BEGIN TRANSACTION SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED SELECT bla.id from BlaTable bt WITH(UPDLOCK) INNER JOIN BlaDetails bd on bd.BlaId = bt.id WHERE bt.id = 5` This code was executed in a new SQL Management Studio window with SPID 84. I knew the SPID from an earlier try so I was able to filter in the profiler. Before I did anything I executed a `rollback` in order to close any existing connection. Then i started the profiler, executed the code and executed `sp_locks 84`. we use  `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT`

Comment: That's good additional detail and you should edit your question to include it, so people don't have to trawl through the comments. (If you can actually make it so the whole thing is reproducible by others, that would be even better.)

Comment: @Jeroen you#re right. I've added the details in the initial post. Hopefully someone can enlighten this.